# How do assign a specific part of a Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, typeerror

This is what I want to do:

```
a = [[1, 2],[3,4]]
b = np.zeros(shape = (2,2))
b[:, 1:] = a[:,1:]
```

But I get this error message:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: `a` is a list of lists, not a NumPy array, so you can't use NumPy slicing on it.

Comment: `a` is a list and you have a stray comma in the slicing for `a`

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MattDMo has mentioned, you are trying to use numpy slicing on a 2D list. You can fix this by simply converting the list to a numpy array

```py
a = np.array([[1, 2],[3,4]])
b = np.zeros(shape = (2,2))
b[:, 1:] = a[:,1:]
```